# Definition of rotations of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, rotations

What's the formal definition for a matrix to be considered as a rotation matrix, what properties must have and why (if that's easy to be answered)

for example why this matrix represents counterclockwise rotation about the positive z-axis by angle $\phi$

$R_z(\phi) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks!

Comment: $SO(3)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group

Comment: "By definition, a rotation about the origin is a transformation that preserves the origin, Euclidean distance (so it is an isometry), and orientation (i.e. handedness of space)" how can we check if a transformation preserves the orientation? , doesn't change the +,- ?

Comment: "The orthogonal matrices with determinant 1 form a subgroup called the special orthogonal group, denoted SO(n), consisting of all direct isometries of O(n), which are those that preserve the orientation of the space."